# angularJS uncaught error

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I'm trying to send some data using POST method in angularjs in codeigniter framework. 
I have loaded angularjs like this

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/custom.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js">
```

But i get an error like this

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3…3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAwtCW2012002%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A421)
```

how do i fix this?

**EDIT**

**CONTROLLER**

This is the controller i have used.

```
;
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').controller('questionAddCtrl', ['$scope','$state','ngRoute','ngResource','$timeout', '$http',  function ($scope,$resource, $timeout, $http) {


                                  $scope.data = {

                                   question:'',
                                   ans1:'',
                                   ans2:'',
                                   ans3:'',
                                   ans4:'',
                                   ans5:'',
                                   correct_ans:''

                                   };

                                    $scope.submit = function(selectData) {


                                        console.log("submit pressed");

                                    //$scope.submitButton=true;

                                   var questionAddRequest= {

                                       "question":selectData.question,
                                       "answerOne":selectData.ans1,
                                       "answerTwo":selectData.ans2,
                                       "answerThree":selectData.ans3,
                                       "answerFour":selectData.ans4,
                                       "answerFive":selectData.ans5,
                                       "correctAnswer":selectData.correct_ans

                                   };


                                   var url = 'http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/restApiController/question';
                                   $scope.jsonData = JSON.stringify(questionAddRequest);

                                   $http({
                                         method: 'POST',
                                         url:   url,
                                         data: jsonData,



                                         })
                                     }


        }]);
})();
```

**HTML**

This is the view page

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="questionAddCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="submit(data)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="question">Question:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" ng-model="data.question" placeholder="Enter Question">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer1">Answer 1:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer1" ng-model="data.ans1" id="answer1" placeholder="Enter Answer 1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer2">Answer 2:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer2" ng-model="data.ans2" id="answer2" placeholder="Enter Answer 2">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer3">Answer 3:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer3" ng-model="data.ans3" id="answer4" placeholder="Enter Answer 3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer4">Answer 4:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer4" id="answer4" ng-model="data.ans4" placeholder="Enter Answer 4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="answer5">Answer 5:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer5" id="answer5" ng-model="data.ans5" placeholder="Enter Answer 5">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="sel1">Select Correct Answer:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> 
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="data.correct_ans" id="sel1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide your html  ?

Comment: Use the development version of angular for more verbose error output. Also you have duplicate scripts loading and should never need bootstrap.js and angular-ui-bootstrap together

Comment: That error is a missing module error

Comment: what seems to be the missing module?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Using an unminified version of angular js gives you more detailed error reports ofcourse makes your debugging easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you first create the "app" module, you need to pass in a second parameter with the module dependencies:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', ...]).controller(...)
```

See angular documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

And here's a fiddle based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/2zm6vp44/

It doesn't completely work but at least there's no module loading error.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?